# how can i print the interarrival_times values in code to a seperate csv or excel file using pandas?

Tags: python, excel, csv, numpy, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

d=pd.read_csv("filepath" ,sep=';' )

links = ["I1"]

for l in links:
    ldict = {}

 for (gi, g) in d[(d["edge_id"] == l) & (d["vehicle_pos"] >= 380)].groupby(["vehicle_id"]):

 ldict[gi] = g.ix[g["timestep_time"].idxmin()]["timestep_time"]

   sorted_list = sorted(ldict.items(), key = lambda (a,b) : b) 

   arrival_times = [v for (k, v) in sorted_list]

   interarrival_times = np.diff(arrival_times)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.DataFrame.to_csv`:

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

d=pd.read_csv("filepath" ,sep=';' )

links = ["I1"]

for l in links:
    ldict = {}

 for (gi, g) in d[(d["edge_id"] == l) & (d["vehicle_pos"] >= 380)].groupby(["vehicle_id"]):

 ldict[gi] = g.ix[g["timestep_time"].idxmin()]["timestep_time"]

   sorted_list = sorted(ldict.items(), key = lambda (a,b) : b) 

   arrival_times = [v for (k, v) in sorted_list]

   interarrival_times = np.diff(arrival_times)

interarrival_times_df = pd.DataFrame(interarrival_times)
interarrival_times_df.to_csv('interarrival_times.csv')
```

See the `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv` [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) here.